# formset and input text for each foreign key

Tags: django, input, initialization, foreign-keys, formset

In my `django formset`, I am trying to display a `foreign key` field with an `input` instead of a `select`:

```
class MinAttend(models.Model):
    act = models.ForeignKey(Act)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    verbatim = models.ForeignKey(Verbatim)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.verbatim

class MinAttendForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), empty_label="Select a country")
    status=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Status.objects.values_list('status', flat = True).distinct(), empty_label="Select a status")
    verbatim=forms.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        model=MinAttend
        #fields used for the validation and order
        fields = ('country', 'status', 'verbatim')
```

For the verbatim field, I do have an input box instead of a select but when I want to update a formset, I have the verbatim id instead of its corresponding text:

[image]

Here is how I initialize the form:

```
class MinAttendUpdate(UpdateView):
    object=None
    model = MinAttend
    form_class=MinAttendForm
    nb_extra_forms=3

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        attendances=MinAttend.objects.filter(...)
        #set the number of forms to the number of ministers + 3 extra form to fill if needed
        MinAttendFormSet = modelformset_factory(self.model, form=self.form_class, extra=len(attendances), max_num=len(attendances)+self.nb_extra_forms, can_delete=True)
        formset=MinAttendFormSet(queryset=attendances)
```

I have tried two things:

Instead of the last line I have the following code:

```
initials=[]
#display text of verbatim instead of id
for index in range(len(attendances)):
    initials.append({"verbatim": attendances[index].verbatim.verbatim})
print "initials", initials
formset=MinAttendFormSet(queryset=attendances, initial=initials)
```

I have overridden the `init` method of the form:

```
#~ #verbatim text instead of id for the verbatim field
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MinAttendForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = kwargs.get("instance", None)
    if instance!=None:
        print "instance", instance.verbatim.verbatim
        self.fields["verbatim"].initial = instance.verbatim.verbatim
```

None of these methods works, I still get numbers instead of text! What is curious is that I do see text for the verbatim field but only for the three extra forms. Normal?

### EDIT - from Bernd Jerzyna comment

In my **form**:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet

class MinAttendFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MinAttendFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            #skip extra forms
            if not form.empty_permitted:
                form.fields['verbatim'].initial= form.instance.verbatim
                print "verbatim MinAttendFormSet", form.instance.verbatim
```

In my **view**:

```
from forms import MinAttendForm, MinAttendFormSet
my_formset = modelformset_factory(self.model, form=self.form_class, formset=MinAttendFormSet)
formset = my_formset(request.POST, queryset=attendances)
```

When I do a print of the text of each verbatim, I see the correct text displayed. However, I still see numbers (primary key ids) in the form of my web page ;(.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

Implement the **init** method of your formset like

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...
super(MinAttendFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

for form in self.forms:
     form.fields['verbatim'].initial= form.instance.verbatim
```

That would also require your Verbatim model to have something like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

Comment: I don't think it can work since the `init` method is declared inside my form (`class MinAttendForm(forms.ModelForm):`), which means it just  sees one form at a time. When I use you code, I get the error: `'MinAttendForm' object has no attribute 'forms'`. What should I do next?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's why I suggested implementing this in the formset ... :)

Comment: I have updated my first post according to your last comment. It still does not work :(.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of it...

As a select widget, the verbatim is displayed with the  `__unicode__` results, but the value 'behind the scenes' is the PK/verbatim-id, *ie* the HTML `<option>` tag has a value and 'label'. When you change it to a text input widget, it is expecting you to enter the PK, hence why you are seeing the numbers.

For the solution, I am not sure. You could write some code to accept the verbatim-text, rather than the pk/verbatim-id. The problem with this though, is that if the text is not written exactly, django won't find a match. Also, if more than 1 verbatim has the same text, django wouldn't know which one to use (unless you have set [unique=true](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) on the model field for text). You could also set the verbatim-text as the PK.

Perhaps using something like [Django-Select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) will give you the desired UI?

Comment: How to implement your solution? My problem is not about writing the verbatim into the inputbox but rather displaying the verbatim.